# How to click each link individually in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Try to separate both links individually by clicking each of them. What should I edit or add?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    if ($('#user').val() != '') {
        alert('For demonstration purposes only. Please do not point your RSS reader to this server.');
        var user = $('#user').val();
```

First One

```
$('#output')
  .html('')
  .append('hhtp://www.breakingnews.com/feeds/rss/' +
    $('#user').val())
  .attr('href', 'http://www.breakingnews.com/feeds/rss/' +
    $('#user').val());
```

Second One

```
 $('#output')
  .html('')
  .append('https://www.theguardian.com/world/' + user +
    '/rss')
  .attr('href', 'https://www.theguardian.com/world/' + user + '/rss');
```

Comment: what are you talking about?

Comment: Click function connects 2 links together when I hover the mouse, but I want to have each clickable link instead of both links together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    var user = $('#user').val();

$('#output')
      .html("")
      .append(jQuery('<a>').attr('href', 'hhtp://www.breakingnews.com/feeds/rss/' +
            user).text('hhtp://www.breakingnews.com/feeds/rss/' + user));
$('#output')
    .append('<br/>')
    .append(jQuery('<a>').attr('href', 'https://www.theguardian.com/world/' + user + '/rss').text('https://www.theguardian.com/world/' + user + '/rss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="user" value="user"></input>    
<div id="output"></div>
```

Problem is in

```
.html('')
```

when you add new link you erase all html content added before.

You should to remove this method in second link creation code.

And you should create a link element

Comment: in this example user keyword will be get from input field, so user can pass it into input himself. var user = $('#user').val(); You just need create links after input changing

Answer (score 0):

Create a link, you are adding a attributes to a text

```
var user = "user";
    $('#output').empty().append('<a href="https://www.theguardian.com/feeds/rss/' + user +'/rss">https://www.theguardian.com/feeds/rss/' + user + '/rss</a>').append('<hr><a href="https://www.theguardian.com/world/' + user +'/rss">https://www.theguardian.com/world/' + user + '/rss</a>');
```